# Save file with data in created program

Tags: c#, save, user-input, windows-forms-designer, savefiledialog

I made a program with my own extension *.cpd*. When I install it and run, it works great, only problem is saving data. I can open file with double click or from my program, but when I save, it stay blank.I used toolstrip for save/open.

I used this code:

```
private void SaveProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Cpd File|*.cpd";

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (Stream s = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
                {
                    sw.Write(textbox1.Text);
                    sw.Write(combobox1.Text);
                    sw.Close();
                    sw.Dispose();
                    s.Close();
                    s.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

What is wrong here? Why it won't accept my input?

Comment: use `sw.close();sw.Dispose();s.close();s.Dispose();` after all write

Comment: place breakpoint in line **sw.Write(*****);** and check: exetute it?

Comment: yes. it says Text="200" . 200 is my input

Comment: please show changed code with **Close** and **Dispose** methods

Comment: you said like this... it cant be put anywhere else tho becouse it will go out of scope, wont exist..

Comment: I don't know... I have this code works fine! Check destination file. Better to remove it and check whether it is created anew

Comment: can you accidentally write to another folder, and check other file?

Comment: how you mean another folder?? upon save i choose where to save it...

Comment: try check it without `savedialog`. Set **filepath** (for example) **c:\text.txt**

Comment: copy this `Stream s = File.Open(@"c:\test.txt", FileMode.CreateNew);StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);sw.Write("!!TEST!!");sw.Close();sw.Dispose();s.Close();s.Dispose();` in your code instead body **SaveProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click** function

Comment: i will try it now.. i managed to export to notepad and word (with .txt and .doc exstensions, but my thing as described above wont work... wont save my input in textbox

Comment: hmmm... i tried one thing now and when i open it with notepad i get inputed text

Comment: `Stream` does not depend on the file name. Search error other place!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
dude you need to close and dispose the stream out of the second using.

```
 if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (Stream s = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
                {
                   using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
                   {
                       sw.Write(textbox1.Text);
                       sw.Write(combobox1.Text);
                       sw.Close();
                       sw.Dispose();
                   }
                   s.Close();
                   s.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Bad idea. if there can be written binary data. We must find the root of the problem!

Comment: i don't understand what you mean with: if there can be written binary data.
can you explain a little?

Comment: in **ante stipe** `Stream` not write in file. Need deal with this problem! may in the future he (she) will write there BinaryData.

Comment: if you want to use it with stream here look at this:
string text = textbox1.Text+combobox1.Text; 
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\YourDest\YourFile.cpd");
file.WriteLine(text);
file.Close();
are you satisfied  Дмитрий Чистик, the more you make things complex the lesser it will work. try simpler things.

Comment: in fact you have written the same thing as the **ante stipe**. But in her (his) it not working.

Comment: thnx  Дмитрий Чистик you made me realize that he was closing the stream before completing the streamwriter his job.

Comment: as i said, s.Close and Dispose can't be there because then there is an error, it goes out of scope.
s does not exist in current context

Comment: strange, her (his) **Close** and **Dispose** `Stream` and it still does not work. :/

Comment: to **ante stipe**:  **virusivv** forgot place **{ }** after `using (Stream s`

Comment: Дмитрий Чистик i don't understand a word you try to say, i gave the reason why his(her) code is not working, you said: as i said, s.Close and Dispose can't be there because then there is an error, it goes out of scope. s does not exist in current context, s does exist in context, because it's parent is using it, but you can't close it before you complete your work. also can you be more specific where i have forgot to use brackets?

Comment: after `using (Stream s = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))` and after `s.Dispose();`